# Why local svg icons not resolve in react.js projects?

Tags: reactjs

I have local icons, and I add icons in build folder like screenshot below, then I was import icons like that `import {ReactComponent as MyIcon} from "build/icons/my-icon.svg";`, but still say "Can't resolve 'build/icons/my-icon.svg'", any idea?

Screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 1):

you need to use [file-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-loader)

and when you import dont use brackets since its default export just chose the name directly

```
import myIcon from "build/icons/my-icon.svg";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <img src={myIcon} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Svg tag

second option would be to extract the svg tag and put it directly into you component ,

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <svg  ....  // copy the content of your .svg
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Also, I wouldn't put anything manually in the build folder - it usually gets wiped during builds. Put the icons in you src folder and they will be added to the build.

Comment: does your webpack loads svg ? check your webpack you need to have a rule for file-loader that has svg in its test

Comment: @HijenHEK, I am not use webpack, I use yarn

Comment: yarn is a package manager i am talking about the bundler , if your not using webpack , are you using gulp ?

Comment: @HijenHEK, I know term of front-end , the problem my project cannot work with webpack,

Comment: just use any file-loader , gulp has one too , what is your bundler ?

Comment: I can use gulp, but can u update ur answer for gulp

Comment: sorry i never used gulp but you still can use the svg directly i updated my answer ,

Comment: @HijenHEK, not for me, for other user